# CorePlot framework with universal build for Mac Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, core-plot, apple-silicon

Is there a way to compile the CorePlot framework as a universal build including arm architectures ?

When I open the project on Xcode 12, I make sure I select Standard Architectures but it doesn't seem to be working. I've test it with the file command on terminal I only get 1 build for x86_64.

Is there a way to check what the $(ARCHS_STANDARD) variable value is ?

CorePlot framework:
https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the code on the `release-2.4` branch. Choose "Any Mac (Apple Silicon, Intel)" instead of "My Mac" from the Scheme menu  at the top of the window before building the framework.

```
$ lipo -info (build folder)/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot 
Architectures in the fat file: (build folder)/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot are: 
x86_64 arm64
```

Comment: Much Appreciate it